# How to do this Birthdays in the next two weeks using Responsys MYSQL

Tags: mysql, responsys

I'm setting up a segment using SQL and I need to capture contacts that birthday will be 15 days from now.

```
SELECT   *
FROM     $A$
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM BIRTHDATE) = EXTRACT(month FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
AND EXTRACT(day FROM BIRTHDATE) = EXTRACT(day FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 15)
```

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802351/mysql-where-date-15-days

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL WHERE Date > 15 Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802351/mysql-where-date-15-days)